# Deleted sheet using VBA appears again if we close the script and rerun it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a sheet using macro and also the corresponding text containing the sheet name which was deleted is also to be deleted from the table in column BP simultaneously. Everything is working well. But when I close excel and open and run the script again. The sheet which was previously deleted again appears back. I am attaching the code as shown below

Kindly help. What could be the reason for this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String

Dim z As Long
    Dim last As Long

ThisWorkbook.Activate

sheetName = Application.InputBox("Please enter the OSAT Name:", "OSAT", _
, , , , , 2)
    last = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataStorage").Cells(Rows.Count, "BP").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err.Clear

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xWs = Sheets(sheetName)

    If Err <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "The OSAT '" & sheetName & "'" & "does not exist!", vbInformation, "Excel 10 Tutorial"

        Exit Sub

    Else

        xWs.Delete

        MsgBox "The OSAT '" & sheetName & "'" & "has been deleted!", vbInformation, "Excel 10 Tutorial"
        
    For z = last To 2 Step -1
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataStorage").Cells(z, "BP").Value = sheetName Then
            Sheets("DataStorage").Cells(z, "BP").Delete
        End If
    Next z
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Removing `On Error Resume Next` is often a good start in understanding why something doesn't work.

Comment: Getting no error upon doing that

Comment: Did you save the workbook after deleting the sheet? Are there any other macros running on opening the workbook? The code looks ok for what you want to achieve

Comment: While testing it in design mode, it works okay. If I generate an add in excel and run it after adding it in then I get the above anomaly.

Comment: When you put this code in an addin, you should not use `ThisWorkbook`.  Rather,  get a reference to the workbook you want to handle,  and use that.  Also use it for your unqualified workbook references

Comment: Thank you Chris, Could you help me with the alternate method to use in place of ThisWorkbook please.

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines contained in the previous comments are very important and must be followed.

To temporarily test for a solution, try this, substituting `xWs.Delete` with these lines:

```
 Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
 Set oWB = xWs.Parent
 xWs.Delete
 oWB.Save
```

Comment: I tried the above code but the deleted sheet still comes back if I reopen excel and run the add in